# How to fix Django warning "(models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type"?

Tags: django, django-models

I just updated my python from 3.9.1 to 3.9.4, and I'm now getting these warnings in the console:

```
WARNINGS:
learning_logs.Entry: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the LearningLogsConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
learning_logs.Topic: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the LearningLogsConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
No changes detected in app 'learning_logs'
```

How do I fix this?  I read the [Django documentation for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/) but I still don't understand.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'backgroud_images', null = True, blank = True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text



class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Entries"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer with console logs as a text instead of screenshot?

Comment: @Nuts how do I copy text from command prompt?

Comment: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-windows-10-command-prompt-copy#:~:text=Now%20you%20can%20select%20text,paste%20it%20in%20the%20window.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Your models do not have primary keys. But they are being created automatically by django.

You need to choose the type of auto-created primary keys:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#customizing-type-of-auto-created-primary-keys (new in Django 3.2)

Either add this to `settings.py`:
`DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.AutoField'`

or

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Comment: Where do I add this into settings. Can this be added anywhere or at start or end?

Comment: Anywhere, but just add it at the end

Answer (score 69):

You have unintentionally updated Django to 3.2 which warns you, and as the hint text suggests, you have to set `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#customizing-type-of-auto-created-primary-keys).
This way you avoid unwanted migrations in future releases as
the value of `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` will eventually be changed to `BigAutoField`.

You should set `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` explicitly to the current `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` value:

> `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'`

You could configure it on a per-app basis (if you expect to build new apps with current style primary key):

> ```
> from django.apps import AppConfig
>
> class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
>     default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
>     name = 'my_app'
> ```

or per-model (discouraged)

> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class MyModel(models.Model):
>     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
> ```

---

You should also version-lock your requirements as you could introduce backward-incompatible changes in production.

Comment: This is the full explanation with all the options listed, thank you

Answer (score 24):

new created project `settings.py` file in **django 3.2**
includes this:

```
..

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

and as your project was created on earlier versions of django so you can **append this** to your settings.

Answer (score 6):

```
models.py:
       class Topic(models.Model):
           id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

`primary_key=True` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#primary-key

```
settings.py:
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

`DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

Comment: Can you update your answer to include an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

Django wants you to add the serial number that's called by primary key and if you can ignore this warning then okay django will automatically add the primary key otherwise, if you want to remove this warning then add this code in your defined model:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

For example:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
```

HaPpY Coding