# Warning: Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'

Tags: django, django-models

Why this is showing a warning as it default take the primary key from the User model so should I also declare the primary key the Registration or candidate model again.
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Registration(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
    dob=models.DateField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname

class candidate(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    total_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} -- {}".format(self.full_name,self.position)
```

problem occured

```
WARNINGS:
poll.candidate: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the PollConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto-create primary key used when not defining a primary key type warning in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66971594/auto-create-primary-key-used-when-not-defining-a-primary-key-type-warning-in-dja)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you define a model in Django without specifying a primary key, Django will automatically create a primary key for you. The primary key is set to be an integer. If you want to override the field type, you can do so on a per model basis.

Starting in Django 3.2, you can now customise the type of the automatically created primary key in your settings.

Starting new projects in Django 3.2, the default type for primary keys is set to a BigAutoField which is a 64 bit integer. However, earlier versions set the type of implicit primary keys to be integers.

This means that when you upgrade to 3.2, you will start to see warnings about the fact that you do not have an explicitly defined primary key type. Satisfying Django's requirements for an explicitly set primary key type is easy enough, but you also need to choose whether or not you want to upgrade your primary key field types from integer to 64 bit integer.

**There are a few ways to fix this. Broadly speaking they fall into two categories**

**Configure DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD in settings**

Open your project's settings.py and add a new line at the bottom of the file

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

**Setting on a per app basis**

If you prefer to set your field type on a per app basis rather than for the whole project, you can specify this in apps.py.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
    name = 'Myapp'
```

**Set AutoField or BigAutoField on a per model basis**

If you prefer even more fine grained control, you can set a per model id field.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because in Django 3.2, primary keys are not created by default and you should define them manually, or you can configure it to be created automatically in your `settings.py`. Note that in newly-created Django 3.2 projects, it's added in your `settings.py` automatically and you don't need to do this.

This question has been answered in stackoverflow before here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66971594/auto-create-primary-key-used-when-not-defining-a-primary-key-type-warning-in-dja).